# TFS 2015 Build Definition source version

Tags: tfs-2015

When queuing a new build I want to specify a label, as says in the Tooltip (see image below) like:

**LMain_TestProject_1.01.002**

However, that does not work, I have to put it with this format:
**LMain_TestProject_1.01.002@$/TestProject**

What I have to do to only specify the source version as: **LMain_TestProject_1.01.002** ??

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Few questions.... first, is the Build Definition hosted by the TestProject project? Is your Build Definition configured to be scoped to "Collection" or "Project" on the general tab? Is there a second label with the same name, but a different scope?

Comment: Try running the following command on the Visual Studio 2015 command line: `tf vc labels Main_TestProject_1.01.002@$/` if it returns more than one item, then that's probably why you need to be more specific in the UI.

Comment: Build definition is project scoped. Running tf vc labels Main_TestProject_1.01.002@$/, return only 1 item. Both project scoped and collection scoped does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually because the label you created is project-scoped, not collection-scoped. In this scenario, you need to add "@/ProjectName".

Usually, when you create a label from VS, you should see the seting like following:
[image]

With this setting, the label is project-scoped. You need to enter "LTestLable@/EddieLabel" when queue build.

More information for your reference: [Label scope revealed](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/03/label-scope-revealed.html).

Comment: Your info is partially correct. From the UI, there is no way to declare scope. The path references what you are versioning. I don't want to version the entire collection, just a project. As you article, the scope only can be set using command line.

Comment: @nerlijma Sorry for make you confused. When you apply a label for the entire collection, then you just need to enter the label name without specify the project. That's what I mean. I will remove this section from my answer to avoid confusion. :)